Does the voltage distribution across series connected capacitors depend on initial conditions?
Assuming two capacitors C1 and C2 are connected in series and completley discharged (vc1 = 0, vc2 = 0 at time t < 0). At time t = 0, the series connection of capacitors is connected to a DC voltage source V1.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage distribution at t > 0 is a function of the capacitances C1 and C2 but only in the case that both capacitors were previously discharged. What happenes if the capacitors were previously charged to some voltages Vc1 and Vc2?

Welcome! Are your capacitors ideal or do they have any leakage (parasitic parallel resistor)?

Yes.  A simple insight:

When the switch is open, both capacitor voltages VC1 and VC2 are independent.
When the switch is closed, a degree of freedom has been removed: now, VC1 + VC2 = V1.

Assuming charge is conserved in the circuit (this occurs by adding some series loss resistance* and any non-negative inductance, switching exactly once, and letting t → ∞), the final value of the C1-C2 node can be solved from initial voltages and the conservation of charge.
*Any positive resistance will suffice; behavior is undefined in the limit as R → 0+, but we generally assert that the same is true at exactly R = 0.  This is an imaginary condition, anyway: any real circuit has nonzero inductance, and any resistance will suffice to turn the solution from an oscillating one to an eventually-steady one.


Does the voltage distribution across series connected capacitors depend on initial conditions?

Yes. Series capacitors do not behave quite like a voltage divider. But if we assume the capacitors have no initial charge, the behave like a voltage divider.

First, there must be a resistor in the circuit otherwise the peak charging current will be infinite:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Second, I'm assuming the capacitors are ideal.
And third, I'm assuming the sum of initial charges are not greater than the supply voltage.

There's only one path for the current to flow. So the total amount of charge change, \$\Delta Q\$, has to be equal for both capacitors.
$$
\mathrm{
\Delta Q = C \cdot \Delta V = C_1 \ \Delta V_{C1} = C_2 \ \Delta V_{C2}
}
$$
Now if the initial conditions of both capacitors are zero i.e. \$\mathrm{V_{C10}=V_{C20}=0}\$ then for \$t>0\$ the capacitors will share the supply voltage proportional (inversely) to their capacitances. So, for the circuit above, the voltage across C1 would be 3V.

What happenes if the capacitors were previously charged to some voltages Vc1 and Vc2?

That's a bit tricky. First, we know that for \$t>>0\$ the total voltage across the capacitors will be equal to the supply voltage. If there's a non-zero initial charge on at least one capacitors (i.e. \$\mathrm{V_{C10}>0}\$ and \$\mathrm{ V_{C20}>0}\$), since the \$\Delta Q\$ must be equal for both as mentioned above, the amount of voltage change will be inversely proportional to the capacitances to meet the total voltage equal to the supply voltage.
$$
\mathrm{
\Delta Q = C \cdot \Delta V = C_1 \ \Delta V_{C1} = C_2 \ \Delta V_{C2} \\
(V_{C10}+\Delta V_{C1}) + (V_{C20}+\Delta V_{C2}) = V_1
}
$$
A numerical example:
For \$t<0\$, let the initial conditions \$\mathrm{V_{C10}=3V}\$ and \$\mathrm{ V_{C20}=4V}\$. So the total is 7V. If the switch is closed at \$t=0\$, the total change of 2V should be distributed amongst the capacitors inversely proportional to their capacitances. So the voltage across C1 should change by 0.67V and the other should change by 1.33V:
$$
\mathrm{
\Delta Q = C_1 \ \Delta V_{C1} = C_2 \ \Delta V_{C2}=10\mu\ \Delta V_{C1}=5\mu \ \Delta V_{C2} \\
\Rightarrow \Delta V_{C2}=2\cdot \Delta V_{C1} \\
\Delta V_{C2}+\Delta V_{C1}=2V \\
\Rightarrow \Delta V_{C2}=2\cdot \Delta V_{C1}=1.33V
}
$$
Finally, the capacitor voltages will be \$\mathrm{V_{C2}=V_{C20}+\Delta V_{C2}=5.33V}\$ and \$\mathrm{V_{C1}=V_{C10}+\Delta V_{C1}=3.67V}\$

The series capacitor total voltage must eventually match the voltage of the source.
There are two scenarios;

Vc1 + Vc2 are greater than the source. At t=0 when the switch is connected the capacitors will flow the supply backwards, assuming the supply can do that.
Vc1 + Vc2 are less than the supply. Current will flow from the supply across the series string. The current will flow until the sum of the voltage is equal to the supply. This is where it gets complicated. The amount of charge stored in to the two capacitors by the current is equal. Series current is the same through out the circuit. Charge is just current * time. The change in voltage of each capacitor is going to depend on the initial voltage/charge. As more charge is progressively stored in each capacitor the voltage is going to rise depending on the capacity of that capacitor. Current flow will stop when the total voltage is equal to the source.

